# Javascript: Access an object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm using **console.log(data.result)** to discover an object hierarchy, here's the output:

[
**Object**
delete_type: "DELETE"
delete_url: "http://doubleyourlikes.com/lab/time/jq-file-upload/server/php/?file=splash%20%2816%29.png"
name: "splash (16).png"
size: 17369
thumbnail_url: "http://doubleyourlikes.com/lab/time/jq-file-upload/server/php/thumbnails/splash%20%2816%29.png"
type: "image/png"
url: "http://doubleyourlikes.com/lab/time/jq-file-upload/server/php/files/splash%20%2816%29.png"
**proto**: Object

> How does a noob like myself access this object ...?  Thanks!  I want the name :)

*Update*
                console.log(data.result) 
                alert(data.result.name);

The alert comes back null!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell since the opening `[` isn't closed, but I assume it means the Object is contained in an array, so you'd access it like:

```
data.result[0].name
```

Comment: Is there an easier way to find out that object is in an array?  You rock that worked perfectly!!

http://screencast.com/t/omwlsuyzw

Comment: Object.prototype.toString.call(data.result) === '[object Array]'

Comment: Thanks for all the help!  So the only way you knew it could have been a part of the array was because I decided to paste in the [ ?  Nice!

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to access `delete_type`, just do `data.result.delete_type` or `data.result['delete_type']`.

Comment: Ok then, with this code:

    console.log(data.result) 
    alert(data.result.name);

the alert comes back undefined?